# Mega-menu for Modern team site

Tags: sharepoint, o365rwsclient

I started a modern team site in SPO and added lots of pages and link to them in the quick link.
Now the users want Mega-Menu instead of the quick link.

I tried to copy the pages to a new communication sites that has mega-menu but there is a difference in the site template that does not let me do it.
I also tried to get the rest call to create the menu with jQuery.

https://{mydomain}.sharepoint.com/{musite}/_api/contextinfo tells me:
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Is there a way to query the quick link and build a mega-menu? 
Any good we to transform a team site to communication site?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your team site is a classic team site then no, you can't have a megamenu unless you make a custom one.

IF your team site is a modern team site then you inherit the megamenu from a hub site I believe.

I have a feeling you have a classic team site with modern pages in it.

Comment: It is a "modern team site" associated with a hub site. but the items of the hub site mega-menu are not the same as the items of the site menu.